# Android GCM putExtra on opening intent

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to use GCM to open an Intent with a given extra as String. The reason why I want to do this is to open a specific fragment and load data from a certain object.

Right now, whenever I get a notification and click on it, my app opens and launches a main Activity. The only thing I need is add extended data to the opening intent (simple string).

Here is the GcmIntentService code:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.e("GCM", "Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.e("GCM", "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification(extras);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(Bundle extras) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String message = extras.getString("message");
        Intent openIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        openIntent.putExtra("hintid", extras.getString("hintid"));
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                openIntent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("StadseBoeren")
        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(message))
        .setContentText(message);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And here is the corresponding main Activity code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("hintid")) {
                String hintid = extras.getString("hintid");
                Log.d("GCM hintid: ", hintid);
                // TODO: Do something with the value of isNew.
            }
        }
```

somehow extras is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the PendingIntent.getActivity(...) factory method is simply re-using the old intent as an optimization, even if it is set to 0. To make sure this doesn't happen, pass the flag PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT like this:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Above is solved my issue. after above changes your getExtra is still null. Please ensure you are put extra is in between Intent and PendingIntent. I did this mistake so i am sharing the same with you.